# How can I prevent date format conversion in Excel after Bootstrap Table export?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

Here is my bootstrap table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13tcW.png)

After exporting to .xls or .csv format, I found that the field 'Enrolled' changed to date format automatically. Here is the excel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpKLx.png)

You can see that, the original value is 5/10 (which means 5 out of 10), but it changed to 10-May after export. Is there any way that I can keep the original value of the field? I do not want it auto changed to date format. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
function loadTable() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin/oes/getReport",
            success: function (dataRaw) {
                var data = JSON.parse(dataRaw);
                
                $('#table').bootstrapTable('destroy');//re-initialize
                $('#table').bootstrapTable({
                    data: data.list,
                    pageNumber:1,
                    pagination: 'client',
                    pageSize: 50,
                    pageList: [20,50,100,200],
                    search: true,
                    //toolbar: "#toolbar",
                    //exportDataType: $(this).val(),
                    exportTypes: ['csv','excel'],
                    exportOptions: {
                        fileName: 'geElectiveReport_' + Date.now()
                    },
                    columns: [{
                        field: 'sectionId',
                        title: 'Section ID',
                        sortable: true
                    }, {
                        field: 'programmeType',
                        title: 'Prog Type',
                        sortable: true
                    }, {
                        field: 'instructor',
                        title: 'Instructor',
                        sortable: true
                    }, {
                        field: 'module',
                        title: 'Module',
                        sortable: true
                    }, {
                        field: 'room',
                        title: 'Room',
                        sortable: true
                    }, {
                        field: 'week',
                        title: 'Week',
                        sortable: true
                    }, {
                        field: 'time',
                        title: 'Time',
                        sortable: true
                    }, {
                        field: 'mediumOfInstruction',
                        title: 'Medium of Instruction',
                        sortable: true
                    }, {
                        field: 'programmeNotAllow',
                        title: 'Programme not Allow',
                        sortable: true
                    }, {
                        field: 'numEnrol',
                        title: 'Enrolled',
                        sortable: true,
                        
                        formatter: (value, row, index, field) => {
                            return value + '/' + row.quota
                        }
                    },
                    ]
                });



            },
            error: function () {
                alert("");
            }
        });

    }
```

I expected that the excel will show the original value which is 5/10, rather than automatically changed to date format 10-May.

Answer (score 0):

There are some extra options that are a part of the tableExport.jquery.plugin that bootstrap-table uses. What might do the trick is [data-tableexport-cellformat](https://github.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin#data-tableexport-cellformat) which should make the numbers into just a string, or at least a format where the numbers are not changed. Here's the relevant excerpt from the docs:

> `<td data-tableexport-cellformat="">...</td> ->` An empty data value
> preserves format of cell content. E.g. no number seperator[sic] conversion

The same link has information for other export types as well if needed.

However, you may want to try opening in something other than Excel to see if it's actually Excel just reformatting it by default and not something inherent in the exported document, in which case you would need to modify your configuration in some way.